# Is it possible that I can override NestJS SessionModule cookie domain during request?

Tags: typescript, session, cookies, nestjs

I have a `NestJS` where I use `SessionModule` for user cookies, and it's all working great, but I need to override the domain name for some requests. Not sure how can I do this in `NestJS`, the actual setting of the domain seems to be in the `imports` array of a module, there is no room where I can inject `req: Request`

```
@Module({
  imports: [
SessionModule.forRoot({
   session: {
     secret: 'someSecret',
      name: `ssid`,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 1234125645654,
        domain: '' // I need to set this sometimes during some requests.
      },
   },
}),
  ],
export class AppModule implements NestModule, OnModuleInit { }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do such thing?

Comment: Why would i not?

Comment: Because even if you manage to do such thing, the browser will ignore it. You can't set cookie for domain A if server is on domain B.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Do you know if it's possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be as easy as `req.session.cookie.domain = 'example.com'`